# How to pretty-print Html 5 files using java or groovy?

Tags: java, html, groovy, pretty-print

I know I can use some classes that I can use to pretty-print xml like [this one](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/10/groovy-goodness-pretty-print-xml.html) in Groovy, but since Html 5 is not necessarily a well-formed xml this will not work.

Are there libraries in java or groovy that will pretty-print html5?

These are valid html 5 files and need not be cleaned, just pretty-printed.

Comment: haven't tried jsoup, care to post it as an answer?

Comment: Why did you add the cleaning part? Isn't my answer good enough? Neko will not clean it, just balance elements, thus making it well formed.

Comment: @ErikPragt just thought to make my particular need easier to understand, that's why I added the explanation that files need not be cleaned. It does not mean you answer is not good enough, although you could have added remarks about Neko to the reply. I prefer to leave the question open for a bit more, just in case someone else wishes to answer. Anyway, thank you for posting your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the examples as demonstrated by Mr Haki, but to clean up the HTML, you can use something like Jsoup or Neko. An example using Neko can be like this:

```
import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser
def url = 'http://java.sun.com'
def html = new XmlSlurper(new SAXParser()).parse(url)
```

This balances the XML elements, and after that, you can easily pretty print it using XmlUtil, for example.